# Example of chainable space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

A *‎chain* in a space ‎$‎X‎$‎ is a finite family of open sets ‎$‎\mathcal C = \{C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_n\}‎$‎ such that ‎$‎C_i\cap C_j \not=‎\emptyset‎‎$‎ if and only if ‎$|i -‎ j|\leq1‎$‎. Space ‎$‎X‎$‎ is *chainable* provided that every open cover of ‎$‎X‎$‎ can be refined by a chain covering ‎$‎X‎$‎.

Can anybody supply an example of a chainable space.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am not familiar with this notion in the first place. But in that case, the question is still missing context, as it should include the source of this nonstandard definition.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Fair enough. Comment deleted and question reopened.

Comment: @Math1000: Thanks; I’ve deleted mine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly such a space must be compact. Let $\langle X,\le\rangle$ be a linear order, give $X$ the associated order topology, and suppose that the resulting LOTS (linearly ordered topological space) is compact. It’s a nice little exercise, not too hard, to show that $X$ is chainable. (First observe that any open cover of $X$ has a finite refinement by open intervals. This refinement has an irreducible subcover, meaning that removing any member of the subcover leaves some point of $X$ uncovered. Now verify that the subcover must be a chain.)

> **Added:** I overlooked the requirement that adjacent members of the chain *must* intersect. That need not be the case if $X$ is not connected. In fact, if $X$ is not connected, it is the union of disjoint, non-empty open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x<y$ whenever $x\in U$ and $y\in V$, and the open cover $\{U,V\}$ has no refining chain. Fortunately, it is sufficient to assume that $X$ is connected, as then adjacent open intervals must in fact overlap.

This isn’t the only way to produce chainable spaces, but it’s a nice general way that produces a lot of examples.

It may also be worth looking for compact spaces that *aren’t* chainable, to get a better idea of just what chainability does for you. One rather easy example is $S^1$, the circle.

Comment: Suppose we modify the def'n of chain to allow a finite or countably infinite chain $\{C_n:n\in \mathbb N\}. $ Under this def'n, $\mathbb  R$ is chainable. But is $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @user254665: I’m inclined to think that it’s not, though I can’t yet prove it.

Comment: I think the impediment in $R^n \;(n>1)$ is that if  $V$ is an open refinement of the open cover $U,$ and $R^n\not \in U,$ and $C_1,C_2\in V$ with $C_1\ne C_2$ and $C_1\cap C_2\ne \phi,$ and  $\partial C_1\not \subset C_2 ,$ then it seems that  there exists $p\in \partial C_1\cap \partial C_2,$ so if $p\in C\in V$ then $C$ intersects both $C_1$ and $C_2.$ It also seems that some open cover can't have an open refinement $\{C_n\}_{n\in N}$ for which  $\partial C_n\subset C_{n+1}$ for all $n.$